# Alsa: how to redirect input to output in .asoundrc?

Tags: linux, alsa, loopback

I have two usb sound cards. The first one is for the playback and the second one is for audio stream capture. I was able to redirect the streams with ecasound:

`ecasound -B:rtlowlatency -b:256 -f:s32_le,2,48000 -i:alsahw,1,0 -o:alsahw,0,0`

But it requires me to start it manually all the time. Is it possible to implement it with alsa, in particularly in `asoundrc` file?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Virtual) devices defined in the `.asoundrc` file are used only when an application opens such a device. So it is not possible to get loopback without running some application (such as `alsaloop` or `ecasound`).